# bower register not hosting package source to Nexus

Tags: json, git, bower, nexus, nexus3

I have few dependencies in `angular.js` application that needs `vpn` to access them, I have to run my application through `docker` container and I don't want to install `vpn` inside of container.

I found way to host that dependencies on `Nexus` Repository Manager, I'm using `bower-nexus3-resolver` npm package, here's my workflow:

1) I created `bower (hosted)` repository in `Nexus` which is accessible with link: `http://localhost:8081/service/rest/repository/browse/bower-internal/`

2) I added following code to my `.bowerrc`:

```
{
    "nexus" : {
        "username" : "admin",
        "password" : "admin123"
    },
    "registry" : {
        "search": [
            "http://admin:admin123@localhost:8081/repository/bower-internal/"
        ],
        "register" : "http://admin:admin123@localhost:8081/repository/bower-internal/"
   },
   "resolvers" : [ "bower-nexus3-resolver" ]
}
```

And I'm running the command `bower register example-package https://github.com/moment/moment.git`, the goal is to store moment or whatever package into nexus but after executing this command there only created `mapping.json` file with the following content: `{ "example-package": "https://github.com/moment/moment.git" }`

What am I doing wrong? How can I store that package on `Nexus` repository?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, it's the way Bower registries work. A Bower registry holds pointers to components that are hosted elsewhere (typically github).

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3M/Bower+Repositories#BowerRepositories-HostingBowerRepositories

BTW, Bower has been deprecated by it's developers.  It would probably be best to use another package manager for your JavaScript dependencies (e.g. npm).

https://bower.io/blog/